# How to connect raspberry pi to cellphone tower and communicate with it by Android phone

Tags: pi-2, data-transfer, gsm

I need to communicate to my raspberry pi with my android phone via cellphone tower. For example,a raspberry pi is connected to nearest base station, if i enter into that base station's range i want to do some actions..for example that raspberry pi is connected to a light, when i enter into that cellphone tower's range, i want to switch on the light.how to use cellphone tower for this project?

Comment: you'll need some sort of cellular network device - I suggest you search for "cellular data raspberry pi" you'll find many suggestions, and even a howto or two

Answer (score 1):

You could easily do that with a GSM Module. You can learn how to use one by typing: "gsm module raspberry pi" in Youtube or Google.